# SQLAlchemy и Python3 - как превратить выборку с повторяющимися значениями в таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Задача наверняка типовая, но я что-то не могу найти инфу.

Мы каждый день получаем информацию и записываем ее в базу данных, допустим примерно так:

```
id  параметр    дата      значение
1 | Параметр1 | 1 января | 100 ед. 
2 | Параметр2 | 1 января | 200 ед.
3 | Параметр1 | 2 января | 101 ед. 
4 | Параметр2 | 2 января | 201 ед.
5 | Параметр1 | 3 января | 102 ед. 
6 | Параметр2 | 3 января | 202 ед.
7 | Параметр1 | 4 января | 103 ед. 
8 | Параметр2 | 4 января | 203 ед.
```

Как на Python и SQLAlchemy принципиально правильно реализовать выгрузку, чтобы вывести в каком-то view вот такую таблицу:

```
параметр    | 1 января | 2 января | 3 января | 4 января
Параметр 1  | 100 ед   | 101 ед   | 102 ед   | 103 ед
Параметр 2  | 200 ед   | 201 ед   | 202 ед   | 203 ед
```

Comment: Принципиально так же, как в чистом SQL - использовать группировки по параметру с датой и агрегатную функцию суммирования на значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае удобно будет воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine(db_connection_string)

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM tab_name', conn)
```

получим DataFrame:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]:
   id   параметр      дата значение
0   1  Параметр1  1 января  100 ед.
1   2  Параметр2  1 января  200 ед.
2   3  Параметр1  2 января  101 ед.
3   4  Параметр2  2 января  201 ед.
4   5  Параметр1  3 января  102 ед.
5   6  Параметр2  3 января  202 ед.
6   7  Параметр1  4 января  103 ед.
7   8  Параметр2  4 января  203 ед.
```

теперь можно построить `PIVOT`:

```
In [119]: res = df.pivot(index='параметр', columns='дата', values='значение')

In [120]: res
Out[120]:
дата      1 января 2 января 3 января 4 января
параметр
Параметр1  100 ед.  101 ед.  102 ед.  103 ед.
Параметр2  200 ед.  201 ед.  202 ед.  203 ед.
```

его можно выгрузить в отдельную таблицу:

```
res.to_sql('new_table_name', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Ого, кажется это то, что нужно. Попробую разобраться с этим модулем.